# How to print the month and the day of the week

Tags: java, date

I want to print the day of the week and the month like.
my next Birth days.
 December monday
 December friday...etc
So far I get to this point.

LocalDate myBirthday = LocalDate.of(2018,6,1);

```
         //int num =myBirthday.getYear();
       //  DayOfWeek day = myBirthday.getDayOfWeek();

    //System.out.println("My next 10 birth days."+ myBirthday);

    for(int i=0; i< 10 ; i++){
        myBirthday.plusYears(i);
       System.out.println( myBirthday.getYear() +" "+myBirthday.getMonth()+ " "+ myBirthday.getDayOfWeek());
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Read the javadoc of plusYears(), carefully.

Comment: How does your result differ from what you wanted? “Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.” Quoted from [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

`LocalDate` class is [**immutable**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). When you call `plusYears(i)`, it returns a new object of `LocalDate` which you are *not* holding.

So you just need to assign the **new reference** again as shown below:

```
myBirthday = myBirthday.plusYears(i);
```

I suggest you refer the javadoc (look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)) for the **LocalDate**'s **plusYears()** below (emphasize mine):

> public **LocalDate** plusYears(long yearsToAdd)
>
> Returns a **copy of this LocalDate** with the specified number of years
>   added. **This instance is immutable** and unaffected by this method call.